# How to use phpexcel to read data and insert into database?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a `php` application where I want to read data from excel, Insert into database and then generate pdf reports for specific users.
I searched a lot but nothing specific given about both things.

Comment: Have you though of exporting your excel data to CSV? Is there something in your data eliminating CSV as an option?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHPExcel library yet?

Comment: @MarkBaker i haven't seen the library yet, although i did try to check out the function reference file but was too big to look into as i had to make this thing work asap in addition to other parts of the project.

Comment: @TelmoMarques we did think of doing it thru a csv but wanted to it using PHPExcel otherwise the last option of csv is always there.

Comment: Can take a look into this tutorial. Hopefully will helpful for you-http://www.tisuchi.com/use-phpexcel-library/

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Using the PHPExcel library to read an Excel file and transfer the data into a database

```
//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
}
```

Anything more becomes very dependent on your database, and how you want the data structured in it

Comment: i tested this today with v 1.7.9, 2013-06-02 and it did not work. i had to replace `$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());` with simple `$sheet->getHighestColumn()`. you may have a bug in the code as you try to get the column index from the string - BUT try to access it via $highestColumn.$row in the loop (which would just give a weird concatenated integer if you didn't use a character)

Comment: Highest column should be a column letter(s) value; so you're right - this should simply be setting `$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();` rather than `$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());` I am not infallible
`

Comment: Code is outdated, to version 1.8.0 update the code to be like this example: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/28iterator.php

Comment: `getHighestColumn()` returns 255 every time. Replacing it with `getHighestDataColumn()` fixes the problem. Here's more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903471/gethighestcolumn-in-xlsx-not-working

Comment: @coder101 Hi. Could u give me your php Pg_Query to Insert row data array into database ? Thankyou

Answer (score 13):

In order to read data from microsoft excel 2007 by codeigniter just create a helper function excel_helper.php and add the following in:

```
      require_once APPPATH.'libraries/phpexcel/PHPExcel.php';
      require_once APPPATH.'libraries/phpexcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
      in controller add the following code to read spread sheet by active sheet
     //initialize php excel first  
     ob_end_clean();
     //define cachemethod
     $cacheMethod   = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
     $cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '20MB');
     //set php excel settings
     PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod(
            $cacheMethod,$cacheSettings
          );

    $arrayLabel = array("A","B","C","D","E");
    //=== set object reader
    $objectReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objectReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objectReader->load("./forms/test.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('Sheet1');

    $starting = 1;
    $end      = 3;
    for($i = $starting;$i<=$end; $i++)
    {

       for($j=0;$j<count($arrayLabel);$j++)
       {
           //== display each cell value
           echo $objWorksheet->getCell($arrayLabel[$j].$i)->getValue();
       }
    }
     //or dump data
     $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
     var_dump($sheetData);

     //see also the following link
     http://blog.mayflower.de/561-Import-and-export-data-using-PHPExcel.html
     ----------- import in another style around 5000 records ------
     $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');
    //=== change php ini limits. =====
    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '50MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
    //==== create excel object of reader
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    //$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    //==== load forms tashkil where the file exists
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("./forms/5000records.xlsx");
    //==== set active sheet to read data
    $worksheet  = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('Sheet1');


    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns          = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();

    echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
    echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
    echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
    echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';
    //----- loop from all rows -----
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) 
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>".$row."</td>";
        //--- read each excel column for each row ----
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) 
        {
            if($row == 1)
            {
                // show column name with the title
                 //----- get value ----
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
                echo '<td>' . $val ."(".$row." X ".$col.")".'</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                if($col == 9)
                {
                    //----- get value ----
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    $val = $cell->getValue();
                    //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
                    echo '<td>zone ' . $val .'</td>';
                }
                else if($col == 13)
                {
                    $date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue())->format('Y-m-d');
                    echo '<td>' .dateprovider($date,'dr') .'</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                     //----- get value ----
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    $val = $cell->getValue();
                    //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
                    echo '<td>' . $val .'</td>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');

    echo "Total time:".$this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');     
    $this->load->view("error");
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library, the following code will do.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';    
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); //optional

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(__DIR__.'/YourExcelFile.xlsx');
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$i=1;
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

    $column_A_Value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A$i")->getValue();//column A
    //you can add your own columns B, C, D etc.

    //inset $column_A_Value value in DB query here

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      if($query)
       {
        // try to export to excel the whole data ---
        //initialize php excel first  
        ob_end_clean();
        //--- create php excel object ---
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        //define cachemethod
        ini_set('memory_limit', '3500M');
        $cacheMethod   = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
        $cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '800MB');
        //set php excel settings
        PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod(
                $cacheMethod,$cacheSettings
              );


        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Field names in the first row
        $fields = $query->list_fields();
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
            $col++;
        }

        // Fetching the table data
        $row = 2;
        foreach($query->result() as $data)
        {
            $col = 0;
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
                $col++;
            }

            $row++;
        }

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        //redirect to cleint browser
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Provinces.xlsx');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
     }
```

Comment: thanks man. Actually i posted this problem months ago and had a workaround that time itself. but i will definitely use your suggestion next time i work on this functionality. thanks again.

Comment: It seems db object

Answer (score 2):

```
    if($this->mng_auth->get_language()=='en')
          {
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setRightToLeft(false); 
          }
                else
                {  
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setRightToLeft(true); 
                }

       $styleArray = array(
                'borders' => array(
                    'allborders' => array(
                        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),
                    ),
                ),
            );

          //SET property
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M10001')->applyFromArray($styleArray);


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M10001')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.chr(65+count($fields)-1).$query->num_rows())->applyFromArray($styleArray);  

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.chr(65+count($fields)-1).$query->num_rows())->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very recent answer to this question from the file: 07reader.php

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


if (!file_exists("05featuredemo.xlsx")) {
    exit("Please run 05featuredemo.php first." . EOL);
}

echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("05featuredemo.xlsx");

$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
echo 'Call time to read Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;
// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;


echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;
echo 'Call time to write Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;
// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;


// Echo memory peak usage
echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;
```

Comment: I'm really unsure how, in any way, this answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Inci framework  you can do download like so:

```
function clubDownload($clubname)
{

    $this->load->library("excel");

    $object = new PHPExcel();
    $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->load->model('Members_student_model');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE $clubname!=''  order by id desc");
    $resultdatanew=$query->result_array();
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1;

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("B1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');


    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("C1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("D1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');


    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("E1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("F1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');
    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("G1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("H1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');
    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("I1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('330000');
    $headerStyle = array(
                'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb'=>'CCE5FF'),
                ),
                'font' => array(
                        'bold' => true,
                )
        );

    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.'I1')->applyFromArray($headerStyle);
    $table_columns = array("id", "studentid", "passport", "lastname", "firstname","university","commencing",$clubname,"added_date");
    $column = 0;
    foreach($table_columns as $field)
    {
    $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
    $column++;
    }
    $excel_row = 2;




    foreach($resultdatanew as $row)
    {


                $id=$row['id'];
                $studentid=$row['studentid'];
                $passport=$row['passport'];
                $lastname=$row['last_name'];
                $firstname=$row['first_name'];
                $passport=$row['university'];
                $commencing=$row['commencing'];
                $email_id=$row['email_id'];
                $added_date=$row['added_date'];


                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row,$id);

                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $studentid);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $passport);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, $lastname);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $firstname);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $excel_row, $passport);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $excel_row,  $commencing);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7, $excel_row, $email_id);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, $excel_row, $added_date);


                $excel_row++;
}

$object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="club' .$clubname.'-'.date('Y-m-d') . '.xls');
$object_writer->save('php://output');
```