# getHighestColumn in xlsx not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

Have this code, using PHPExcel

```
    public function getHighestColumn()
    {
      return $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
    }

    public function getHighestRow()
    {
      return $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
    }
```

I have the same excel file saved in .xls and .xlsx
It has 10 columns (From B to K), and 10 rows

When I use `getHighestColumn`, in .xls I'm getting 'K' (correct), but in .xlsx I'm getting AMK (the last column in all excel worksheet)
About the row, using .xls I'm getting 10, but in .xlsx I'm getting 1024.
I'm pretty sure that, except the table, the rest of the worksheet is in blank.

Any ideas why I'm getting different result?

Here are the readers I'm using

```
public function openReader($filePath)
    {
      //aca determinamos cual tipo es para saber que reader es
    $reader_5 = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
    $reader_07 = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

    $inputFileType = $this->canRead(new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5(), $filePath, self::EXCEL5);

    if($inputFileType === '')
      $inputFileType = $this->canRead(new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007(), $filePath, self::EXCEL2007);
    else
    {
      throw new Exception("No se puede procesar el archivo; el formato no es correcto");
    }
    return PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    }


private function canRead($reader, $path, $readerType)
  {
    return $reader->canRead($path) ? $readerType: '';
  }

public function persist($fileName)
    {
      $filePath = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'\\'.$fileName;

      $this->objReader = $this->openReader($filePath);
      //Set only first Sheet
      $this->setOnlyFirstSheet();

      $this->createObjPHPExcel($filePath);

      echo $this->getHighestColumn();
      echo $this->getHighestRow();
     }
```

I've checked with `var_dump` and in each case I'm using the right reader.

php 5.3.5, PHPExcel 1.7.8, Symfony 1.4

Comment: You shouldn't be getting 'B' for the highest column in the xls file if you have data in column 'K'.... but open the xlsx file in MS EXcel and do Ctrl-End to see what it thinks the last cell is

Comment: Also, because rows and columns are counted by getHighestColumn() and getHighestRow() if they contain _anything_ (including style information) rather than simply having content, look at the getHighestDataColumn() and getHighestDataRow() methods

Comment: I mean, getting 'K', was a typo. Checking that methods

Comment: @MarkBaker it works like a charm!! Thank you, please post it as an answer, so I can tick it as correct

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rows and columns are counted by `getHighestColumn()` and `getHighestRow()` if they contain anything (including style information) rather than simply having content. These values are also calculated when the spreadsheet is loaded, so may not be accurate if you subsequently add new rows or columns to the worksheet.

Instead, use the `getHighestDataColumn()` and `getHighestDataRow()` methods to return the highest row and column that actually contain data values in cells. While less efficient, they actually calculate the highest cell reference when called, which is slower, but always accurate

Answer (score 1):

```
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();    
$colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.