# get values from $rowData

Tags: php, excel

I`m trying to make a simple page in php where data from an excel sheet is displayed.

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695695/how-to-use-phpexcel-to-read-data-and-insert-into-database).

when I use foreach loop to print the values of $rowData I get only one value printed.
My Excel Document consists of 2 Columns Attendance and register number only the first value is displayed.

here`s teh foreach am using

```
foreach($rowData as $row){
    foreach($row as $var){
         echo "{$var}<br/>";
    }
}
```

I searched for information regarding rangeToArray method but am not able to get information regarding what parameters are passed to it.Please can someone explain how the method works..

Edit: output when print_r used

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Register Number 
        [1] => Attendance 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => UR11CS012 
        [1] => 0.78 
    ) 
) 
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => UR11CS013 
        [1] => 0.65 
    ) 
) Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => UR11CS015 
        [1] => 0.67
    )
)
```

Edit: here is the code still printing last value only whats wrong ? should i have saved file in a seaprate folder <strike>uploaded file</strike> rather than use it  from the temporary folder

```
<?php
            $name=$_FILES['u_file']['tmp_name'];
                try {
                    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($name);
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($name);
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
                }
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
                $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);      
            }
            print_r($rowData);
        ?>
```

Comment: Could you show us how the array looks like exactly?

Comment: Show us the array, do `print_r($rowData);` before the loop to see the array structure.

Comment: apologies for slow reply have problem with internet

Comment: your print_r output is strange - there should be an enclosing Array() output. maybe you're calling it inside your foreach?

Comment: Looks like you are calling `print_r` inside a loop... Put it outside of the `foreach`

Comment: See my answer below.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you print_r'd the $row and not the $rowData, Either way what I would do is use the [list](http://www.php.net/list) function like this

```
foreach($rowData as $row){
    list($rNum,$atten) = $row;
    echo $rNum .":". $atten ."\n";
}
```

As you always have only two columns using list will help reduce using a loop within a loop.
Also the first echo will be the column names, so you can skip it using a for loop and not a foreach

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($rowData);$i++){
    list($rNum,$atten) = $rowData[$i];
    echo $rNum .":". $atten ."\n";
}
```

This will start you on the second index of the array, essentially skipping the column headers

Comment: I used print_r in a for()  loop From the Link I mentioned above putting print_r outside the loop prints only the last value Currrently only 2 columns but there may be more like cgpa,placement cell atend etc...

Comment: Doing `print_r($rowData);` outside of the loops will print the entire array, not just the last "columns". Anywho... this answer is exactly what you need and will work.

Comment: Please try the solution provided, and let me know if it doesn't work. Then we can try get at it from a different angel. If it does work, please accept it as the valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
```

to

```
$rowData[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
```

Notice the square brackets, this will make it an array. Before it was just over writing the one variable each time....

You will then be able to loop through $rowData using @Beyerz answer above...

**EDIT:** Quick explanation of the what that function is doing.

This is searching the excel file the for last row number with data in it and storing it in `$highestRow`

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
```

This is doing the same but with the columns

```
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
```

It is then looping through starting at 1 until it reaches the $highestRow, and storing the data in each column in the array.

So for example it starts at row A1, gets the data from each column on row A1 up to the `$highestColumn` <- the last column with data on it, and then it loops and grabs each column in A2, then A3... etc...

It stores each row in the array $rowData[]. The `NULL, TRUE, FALSE` are some settings you probably don't have to worry about, like calculating formulas if the cells contain them....

Hope that helps...

Comment: @supersonic Thank You! :) can you also explain about rangeToArray method like U understand the First argument but the others I don`t know for what I`m passing

Comment: I have not used this PHPExcel class before, but it looks like it is finding the highest row (i.e. the last row with data in it) and then starting at A1 looping through and grabbing the data from each cell. Hang on... I'll update this answer with an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Your `$rowData` contains only one row. there for you have to output the data in the for loop or put the data in an extra array:

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
    foreach($rowData[0] as $var){ 
        echo "{$var}<br/>";
    }     
}
```

or

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $rowData[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
}
foreach($rowData as $row) {
    foreach($row[0] as $var) {  
        echo "{$var}<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: where is my fault? - uh - i forgot []

Comment: $rowData is just getting overwritten each time in the loop, it doesn't magically become an array.... I see you just edited your second example to make it an array, but the first is still not going to work. Unless you edit that before I finish typing this...

Comment: take a look at the print_r output

Comment: You are correct. My apologies, It was the initial formatting, I missed the closing bracket on the second `foreach`.