# How import Excel sheet into MySql table using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, excel

Probably not the correct site to post this question but I am looking for the following:

How to import an excel file sheet data into a MySQL table.
Front end should be AngularJS and Backend is Apache/PHP.
The excel file will be in a directory in the Apache server ready to be imported.

I have tried the following samples but this library is really messy and complicated to use: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

I am just looking for other alternatives if anyone can shed some light thank you so much.

Comment: What's so messy and complicated about [code as simple as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695695/how-to-use-phpexcel-to-read-data-and-insert-into-database/9697745#9697745)?

Comment: Note that the latest PHPExcel code is also [on github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) and not on codeplex, which has been "abandoned" for over 2 years now

Comment: I have the some problem.